# How to update / insert data from table belong to database "A" to table belong to a database "B"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

How to update / insert data from table belong to database "A" to table belong to a database "B" ?

For example, I have a table in the name of ips as below belong to database "A":

```
CREATE TABLE `ips` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `begin_ip_num` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `end_ip_num` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `iso` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `country` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Let's assume I have a second table country belongs to database "B":

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
 `countryid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `ordering` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `iso` char(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`countryid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

note :the two database are in the same server

Answer (score 2):

You have to prefix the table names by the DB/schema name. Something like that:

```
INSERT INTO `database B`.`country` (columns) 
    SELECT columns FROM `database A`.`ips`;
```

Of course, you have to replace `columns` by the required column names and/or expression corresponding to your needs.

Comment: @NejmeddineJammeli Everywhere you have a `\`table\``, you could write `\`database\`.\`table\``. If that helped you, don't forget to vote up ;)

Comment: i can't vote it need 15 reputation how can i win reputation point to vote up

Comment: You might not be able to upvote the answer, but you can mark it as the answer.  As far as how do you earn reputation, go to the FAQ.  There is a link on that page which leads you to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer it goes like;

insert into x select * from otherdatabase.owner.table

Which can be expanded to select columns etc..

In Oracle you might need a database link bvetween them. THat was a long time ago for me ;-)